# How to ask UIImageView if MultipleTouchEnabled is "YES"

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, multi-touch, touchesbegan

I have created a few UIImageViews programmatically, but I have a feeling that even though I setMultipleTouchEnabled to YES during the setup, it is not getting set properly and it's leading to multi-touch issues.

My question is, within touchesBegan how do I go about asking the UIImageView that was touched if it has MultipleTouchEnabled or not?

I am fairly new to this so I'm really stumbling through code and learning as I go (with your help of course).

Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multipleTouchEnabled` is a property of `UIView`, so you can check it using the dot syntax for property access by something like:

```
if (aView.multipleTouchEnabled) { NSLog(@"multipleTouch is Enabled"); }
```

Comment: so by doing something like this within touchesBegan?

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
  
UIView *newView = [touch view];

if (newView.multipleTouchEnabled) { NSLog(@"multipleTouch is Enabled"); }
}

Comment: You can make the log more detailed if you want and see which subviews have multi touch enabled:  NSLog(@"multipleTouch enabled in %@", newView);